# Named CFLOCK applied across whole application?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Please can somebody tell me whether named locks apply across the session, application or server?

I have been looking at the documentation and have only managed to confuse myself further.

What I want to be able to do is to name a lock dynamically (based on a user ID for instance) and have this lock apply application wide. I do not want to lock the whole application scope because this would be overkill.

Comment: How were you intending to use these locks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apply to the entire CF *instance*, which isn't quite what it says in the docs ("[CFLOCK](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflock#cflock-Attributes)"):

> Lock names are global to a ColdFusion server.

The difference between reality and what the docs say is that there can be more than one CF instance running on a given server; locks in instance `A` will not exist as far as instance `B` is concerned.